# Reverse knot and reflection

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I have read about, assuming we are given a Knot $K$, the reverse knot of $K$ and the reflection of $K$.

Can somebody please tell me, what these knots are? Maybe through an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse of an oriented knot is the knot with the opposite orientation.  The reflection of a knot diagram is the same diagram with all the crossings switched; undercrossings to overcrossings and overcrossings to undercrossings.  See Lickorish's book "An introduction to knot Theory" page 4.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the reverse of a knot diagram, instead of the reverse of a knot is defined in this answer. The reverse of a knot can be defined as the mirror reflection about any plane of the knot.

Comment: But then you need to define what a plane of the knot is. I assume that what you mean is any plane that does not intersect the knot, and then reflection would mean a non-trivial isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that leaves the plane fixed?  I just took the definitions from the text cited, but perhaps your method would avoid having to use knot diagrams.

Comment: Yes, I believe any plane will do, whether it intersects the knot or not. A reflection in the plane is as is defined in linear algebra. For example, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html